# Referring generically to objects in different families in Java

Tags: java, generics

I have classes belonging to the family `Foo` (`BabyFoo`, `MamaFoo`, `PapaFoo`) as well as classes belonging to the family `Bar` (`BabyBar`, `MamaBar`, `PapaBar`). Within each family, it is easy to refer to the members of the family. For instance, when `MamaFoo` refers to her own child, she refers explicitly to `BabyFoo`. But there are instances when class `Lou` runs code on the members of a family (`Baby`, `Mama`, `Papa`) without knowing which family is handling the request.

How can `Lou` refer generically in Java to a member of either family?

My (poor) solution so far is to use delegation. Lou does not run code on members of the two families. Instead two gateway classes `FamilyFoo` and `FamilyBar` handle all incoming requests from `Lou`.

`FamilyFoo` and `FamilyBar` in turn refer explicitly to classes in their family. This solution turned out to be poor because it results in considerable code duplication, even though polymorphism (`Lou` delegates to a `Family reference`, a parent of both `FamilyFoo` and `FamilyBar`) means that some code economy is achieved.

Can you do better?

Comment: Use interfaces such as `IBaby`, `IMama`, `IPapa`, `IFamily` that expose the operations common across the parallel hierarchies.

Comment: This is a little too abstract for me to understand what you're trying to do. Maybe you could include a code snippet that shows what part is clunky.

Comment: That said, parallel hierarchies are somewhat of a design smell. I'd see about redesigning this, maybe using generics and composition. E.g. you have the classes `Baby<FamilyType>`, `Mama<FamilyType>`, and `Papa<FamilyType>`, and these objects would contain either a `Foo` or a `Bar` (the `FamilyType`) to specialise their behaviour. (Or vice versa.) Still, it's hard to redesign code without knowing its use.

Comment: interesting, please share some code

Answer (score 0):

You should use either an interface which Bar and Foo can implement if it's going to be the same operations for all subtypes.

Instead, if it makes sense you can make a super class which both Bar and Foo can extend. From your explanation I can't be sure which is better. I'd need more information.

**EDIT**: You can use generic family members such as `Baby<T>`, `Mama<T>`, `Papa<T>` for which `T` represents the family.

Comment: The two solutions you propose solve half the problem. The 49% of the code that is external to FamilyFoo and FamilyBar (the code in Lou) is not duplicated. But the 51% of the code that implements the interface  (for your first solution) or that implements the abstract methods (for your second solution) is duplicated. It is identical, save for replacing BabyFoo with BabyBar, and so on. In my case I have four families, and so the code duplication is particularly bothersome.

Comment: Well in that case use @millimoose's suggestion. Create these generic classes: `Baby<T>`, `Mama<T>` and `Papa<T>` where `T` is `Foo` or `Bar`. I'm not too sure what the Foo and Bar classes will contain. That depends on any differences between the families if there are any.